# JavaSript: Replace what variabile is executed from method parameters

Tags: javascript, methods, parameters

Replace what variabile is executed from method parameters

E.g.:

```
     let obj = {};
     let valour;
    function setValues (objProp, varName) {
            obj[objProp] = 3; 
            varName = 3; 
            }
    setValues('valour', valour );
```

I need this results:

```
    obj.valour = 3;
    valour = 3;
```

Comment: `_this[prop] = someValues;`

Comment: Don't reassign `prop` with `prop =`

Comment: _this[prop] and prop are 2 diferent things and they will recive same value,  So I need method parameters to do two things.  setProp('prop')  will solve _this['prop']  but then I will not have acces to the second object => prop

Comment: `prop` is the function parameter. If you reassign it, you lose the value that was passed to the function, and you can't then use it as the index into `_this`

Comment: I think I'm not understanding what you want to do. Please post a [mcve] and explain what the result should be.

Comment: If you reassign it, you lose the value that was passed to the function : Thanks, Got It